# Match against score / relevance column returns 0 when ordered by

Tags: mysql

When I run the query below the score column is always 0:

```
SELECT
    *,
    (
        (MATCH (search.primary) AGAINST ('"test"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 5) +
        (MATCH (search.secondary) AGAINST ('"test"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 2.5) +
        (MATCH (search.tertiary) AGAINST ('"test"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 1)
    )
    AS score 
FROM
    publications 
    LEFT JOIN
        themes 
        ON themeUUID = publicationTheme 
    LEFT JOIN
        search 
        ON search.item_id = publications.publicationUUID
AND search.item_type = 'publication' 
WHERE
    publicationStatus = 'Live'
GROUP BY
    publicationUUID 
HAVING
    score <> 0
ORDER BY 
    score ASC
```

However, when I don't order by score, it returns the properly calculated score.

I'm using MySQL version 5.6.22, this query is working fine on my development server which uses MySQL version 5.7.18.

Any ideas why the score column would always be 0 when ordered by? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At first glance this seems impossible, as you have `HAVING score <> 0`, but then... do you happen to have a column named `score` in one of the tables?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I'm aliasing the calculation made by the match against as score, the query itself is working fine but it's when I try to order by score - the score column always returns 0.

Comment: Yes I understand this. And as mentioned, this doesn't even seem possible given your `HAVING` clause. But I am asking if one of your tables happens to contain a column named `score`, too. Then maybe the DBMS gets confused with the duplicate name.

Comment: There is no other column that I'm selecting with the name score, I'm using having because score is an aggregate column which I'm unable to query it in the where clause. This is a really frustrating issue because it works as expected on my dev server :(

Comment: I understand all this. My question is: may there possibly be a column named `score` in one of the tables? Well, to keep it simple: Please rename `score` to `xxxscore` in your query. Does this solve the problem?